# How to increase script font size in JMeter 4 UI

Tags: jmeter

I am running JMeter 4 in windows.  I read that I can use the following settings to increase font size.

```
-jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
-jsyntaxtextarea.font.size = 28
-jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor = 2.0
```

But I can't figure out where to add this, I try adding it to the jmeter.bat.  But that just give me an error saying those command are not found.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is part of bin\jmeter.properties. see [JMeter configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

> jsyntaxtextarea.font.size
> Change the size of the (JSyntax) Text Areas. Will be used only, when jsyntaxtextarea.font.family is set.
> Defaults to: -1
> No

In order to update it,add lines to user.proprties and reatart JMeter

> The properties present in jmeter.properties or reportgenerator.properties should be set in the user.properties file. These properties are only taken into account after restarting JMeter

Notice also that you have a menu option to Zoom  In.